# Draw a line that doesn't get thicker when image stretches

Tags: css, svg

Is there a way in SVG to draw a line that keeps thin when the image is stretched?

I'm using a SVG image as a CSS background, something like this:

```
<svg ... preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 15 15">
  <line x1="0" y1="15" x2="15" y2="0"
        color="#000" stroke="#333" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
```

(A diagonal line). I'm stretching this image through a rectangular element, and when the element is bigger, the line gets thicker, but I need an always-thin line.

Possible? Something like "thin" lines in flash.

Comment: In what way are you stretching it - with a desktop application or a library of some kind? Can you not reset the `stroke-width` after the transformation?

Comment: I'm using it as CSS background in a webpage. Can't reset stroke-width :/

Comment: I don't know the library at all, but I imagine you could do exactly that with RaphaelJS. Might be worth a go?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In browsers that implement SVG 1.2T you can have a [non-scaling stroke](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke)  Opera and Webkit support this as does Firefox from version 15.

```svg
<!-- via property -->
<line … vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />

<!-- via CSS -->
<style>
  line { vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke }
</style>
<line … />
```

Comment: IE9 doesn't support non-scaling stroke. I don't know whether IE10 support this feature.