# How manage stroke with 2 SVGs with different size

Tags: css, html, svg, stroke

I use since shortly [svg icon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) and stroke property for my website. But when 2 svg have different canvas size, the stroke are drawed before resizing.

So for a svg on 32px and a 2px stroke, the 64px result have 4px strok.. And the second (on 128px) have a 1px stroke on the final result.

For example i have done a Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kX6tL/1/

```
<tr>
    <td>Stroke : 2</td>
    <td> <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#home-icon" /></svg> </td>
    <td> <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#earth-icon" /></svg></td>            
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Stroke : 10</td>
    <td> <svg class="icon large-stroke"><use xlink:href="#home-icon" /></svg> </td>
    <td> <svg class="icon large-stroke"><use xlink:href="#earth-icon" /></svg></td>            
</tr>

.icon{
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;

    fill: #AB1;

    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.large-stroke{
    stroke-width: 10px;
}
```

Someone have a solution ??

Thank you all for reading and help ! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw a line that doesn't get thicker when image stretches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160262/draw-a-line-that-doesnt-get-thicker-when-image-stretches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke".
This property is supported by FF,Chrome,opera and safari except IE.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-SVG2-20140211/painting.html#NonScalingStroke

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I try on my code and it doesn't work (html and css version)
Code with non-scaling-stroke : http://jsfiddle.net/kX6tL/2/

Comment: I try another think and it's work !! I don't have to put this attribute to the svg balise but on the child of the svg. 
So : svg *{ vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; }

Working code : http://jsfiddle.net/kX6tL/3/